# Why db.Key.from_path raise an error when id_or_name and kind are passed as keyword arguments, but not as positional arguments?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

```
>> db.Key.from_path(kind='Entity', id_or_name='name')
# Error 'Excess keyword arguments ' + repr(kwds))

>> db.Key.from_path('Entity', 'name')
# Works okay
```

Was the google.appengine.ext.db.Key.from_path() designed like that for a specific reason?

Comment: `db.Key.from_path('Entity', 'name', 'Subentity', 'name2')` is also a valid invocation. Keyword arguments plainly wouldn't work there.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense now. the function needs to be able to accept an unknown amount of ancestors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because positional arguments can not be passed as keyword (default) argumentss.
This is not a problem of gae but the way python function arguments work.

From [appeng docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass.html#Key_from_path):

```
Key.from_path(kind, id_or_name, parent=none, namespace=None, **kwds)
```

where:

```
**kwds
Keyword arguments. The method supports one keyword argument, parent,
which specifies a parent entity to prepend to the given path.
Its value is the parent's Key.
```

So "kind", "id_or_name" are not keywords but names to indicate positional arguments.